# Can Image Recognition used to find height of a person whole, torso, legs etc

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, image-recognition

Image recognition can be used to classify images. But I wanted to find few parameters like height of person, his legs, his hand etc. Will CNN helpful for this type of output ?

Comment: You can guess, but not really unless you have depth sensing data because your neural network will perceive things differently based on the camera angle.

Comment: @AidenGrossman If every images are taken from constant distance. Like.. If the distance from the person and camera is constant in all images. Will that work ?

Comment: it will probably work, but it still would not be as accurate as a depth sensing camera.